# Составить regex для поиска одинаковых букв в начале и конце слова

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Напечатать без повторения слова текста, у которых первая и последняя буквы совпадают.
Нужно составить регулярное выражение. Но у меня ничего не получается. Помогите.

```
public class Task3 extends SomeText {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String pattern = "((.)\\w*\\2 ?)+\\Z";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Что-то вроде `\b(.).*?\1\b`

Comment: Alexander Petrov,  Ваше выражение ищет по одному слову, а Анатолию скорее всего нужно обрабатывать всю строку.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Попробуйте эту регулярку:

```
  String text = "ололо довод шалаш";
  String pattern = "^(([А-яA-z])[А-яA-z]*\\2 ?)+\\Z";

  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
  Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
  while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(text);
  }
```

Comment: Почему-то вообще ничего не выводит.

Comment: Можно пример кода?

Comment: Отредактировал начальное сообщение.

Comment: Поправил ответ.